# Are Android logging methods asynchronous?

Tags: android, logging, asynchronous, synchronous

The Android Developer documentation does not mention whether **the method below (and similar ones) is synchronous or not: [Log.i(String tag, String msg)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#i%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)**

**Can anyone shed some light on this ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android.util.Log` invokes all of its methods on the calling thread. So yes, it is synchronous (and IMO it would be kind of silly if it wasn't).

You can find the source code [here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/donut/frameworks/base/core/java/android/util/Log.java).

Comment: Not necessarily silly, it depends on the Logging API goals. Although Boost.Log is a C++ library, its logging frontend can be either  synchronous or asynchronous. Hence blocking the calling thread or not. 

IMO as long as the logging API guarantees total order for the logging calls made by my application, I see no major drawback to use such logging library.

@alex-lockwood:Why would it be silly for the Android Logging API to be asynchronous ?

Comment: It's silly because of (1) the overhead of having to launch new threads just to print a small string to the logcat and (2) you'd risk blocking the UI thread which is responsible for generating the UI and receiving touch/click events.

Comment: Alex, how would you (2) block the UI thread just because you try to spawn (another) Thread to run the Log? Or is it tied to the UI in some way? But I agree that it would be silly to code it async anyway.

Comment: @David, sorry you're right. I misread the OP's comment... I could have sworn the OP mentioned something about "thread safety" when I originally read his comment... my bad :P

Comment: Yeah, no problem. It's still not needed (IMO) to code it async, since it's very easy to do if one _wants_ it, while still allowing the choice. Personally, I'm lazy and commonly rely on Log to also "see" where my code goes until breaking... threading could possibly mess with that.

Comment: @David: Even if logging calls run asynchronously, it should still allow you to debug your code using Log class as if Log was synchronous as long as the logging library ensure some kind total order of logging calls for you application. Obviously, if your application has multiple threads, then asynchronous logging might raises additional concerns or make debugging harder.

Comment: True, but that would need additional implementation to ensure that, in case the app force close, the Log lines are still spit out and survive the app itself. And I'm not sure of the implications. Certainly something nice to think about.