# Are Android's lower-level logging features thread safe?

Tags: android, logging, thread-safety

Are Android logging functions such as `Log.d()` and `__android_log_print()` safe to use in a multithreaded context? In particular, I'm wondering if it's guaranteed there will be no instability and that individual log messages won't be interleaved at the character level or otherwise jumbled.

It would seem this should be easy information to find, but for some reason I haven't been able to find anything conclusive. The documentation for [`Log`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log) and for the [corresponding native functions](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/logging) doesn't seem to address the issue. In the documentation for [`Logger`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Logger) it's mentioned that all methods are thread safe, but it's the lower-level functions I'm wondering about specifically.

One would expect these functions to be thread safe, given that logging from multiple threads is probably common. Also, by default at least, in Android Studio each log message includes a thread identifier, and it would seem odd for the logger to be thread-aware but not thread safe.

I highly doubt there's anything to worry about here, but when it comes to multithreading it seems like a guarantee would be preferable, even when it seems obvious that the functionality in question must be thread safe.

Is this documented somewhere, and I've just missed it? If not, is it reasonable to assume that the functions in question are thread safe?

Comment: reasonable to assume: yes. In 10± years of Android I've never seen a garbled LogCat message. Sorry I don't have anything other than anecdotal. How about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11237495/413127

Answer (score 0):

As in my many years as an Android developer, I've used Log.d(), Log.e(), etc, and I've never seen garbled logs or any other weird stuff when calling logs from multiple threads.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35719139)